# runST inside MonadRandom

Tags: haskell, monads

I want to do `runST` inside a Rand-monad, but I can't get the types right and the output from GHC is not particularly helpful:

```
import           Control.Monad
import           Control.Monad.Random as MR
import           Control.Monad.ST
import           Control.Monad.Trans
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed  as VU

shuffle :: (MonadRandom m) => m (VU.Vector Int)
shuffle = do
  k <- getRandomR (0::Int, 10::Int)
  let vec = runST $ do
    vector <- VU.unsafeThaw (VU.enumFromN (1::Int) k)
    vector' <- VU.unsafeFreeze vector
    return vector
  return vec
```

> parse error on input `vector'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error is usually related to indentation issues. If you indent the lines in the `runST` block a bit more, that error will go away.

The next issue is that you're returning the wrong vector (forgot the `'`).

Lastly, binding a value only to use it with the return function on the next line is redundant.

Here is working code:

```
shuffle :: (MonadRandom m) => m (VU.Vector Int)
shuffle = do
  k <- getRandomR (0::Int, 10::Int)
  let vec = runST $ do
              vector <- VU.unsafeThaw (VU.enumFromN (1::Int) k)
              VU.unsafeFreeze vector
  return vec
```

Alternatively,

```
shuffle :: (MonadRandom m) => m (VU.Vector Int)
shuffle = do
  k <- getRandomR (0::Int, 10::Int)
  return $ runST $ do
    vector <- VU.unsafeThaw (VU.enumFromN (1::Int) k)
    VU.unsafeFreeze vector
```

Comment: Excellent. Double-space indentation tabs are really easy to miss. How come it's not necessary to lift `runST` into the random monad? Does return handle that?

Comment: `runST` returns a pure value (in this case your vector), and `return` "puts" the value into the monad.

Comment: Or forget the `do` entirely, since all it's doing is making you invent a name for the temporary vector: `return . runST $ VU.unsafeThaw (VU.enumFromN (1::Int) k) >>= VU.unsafeFreeze`